# How do I handle an empty list in my own version of `last`?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm having trouble getting this simple Haskell function to compile. It is from 99 Haskell Problems, where one should implement `last`. I've written the following version:

```
 myLast :: [a] -> a
 myLast []     = []       
 myLast (x:[]) = x          
 myLast (x:xs) = myLast(xs)
```

However, I get an error if I load it into GHCi:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[t0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for myLast :: [a] -> a at problem1.hs:1:11
Relevant bindings include
  myLast :: [a] -> a (bound at problem1.hs:3:1)
In the expression: []
In an equation for `myLast': myLast [] = []
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Which tells me that

```
myLast[]    = []
```

is the problem.

If I remove it, it gets interpreted correctly. But if I pass the empty list

```
Prelude> myLast []
```

I get

```
> Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast
```

Which makes sense, because I don't have the empty list in the matching criteria. Can anyone explain this error to me and how to fix it?

Comment: last is in fact a very bad function, it's _partial_, it has no proper evaluation for an empty list so the only choice is to error out (either implicitly with a non-exhaustive pattern or explicitly with an `error "last doesn't work on an empty list"` which is slightly better but still crummy to debug in big programs). It's one of those functions you shouldn't use, like `head` or `tail`. If you need a safe last, I would advise looking at the [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) library for _total_ alternatives with saner types. Of course, for an exercise that doesn't matter much ! :)

Comment: Just for fun, can you write `myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a` using `foldl` and no explicit recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an empty list then you can't return an `a` since there is none to return. You could encode this possibility in the type of `myLast` by returning a `Maybe a` instead of an `a`. Then you could return `Nothing` if the list is empty:

```
myLast :: a -> Maybe a
myLast [] = Nothing
```

If you can't change the type of the function, your only option is to raise an error:

```
myLast [] = error "Empty list"
```

Comment: I would add something like: "After all, how do you chose the last element of an empty list? How do you chose _any_ element of an empty list? There is no sensible choice. However, you could change the type of your function a little bit to `myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a` and either return `Just x` or `Nothing`".

Comment: @Zeta I come from a Scala background. That makes ALOT more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your type signature says

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
```

if you pass a list to `myList`, it will give you back a single element of the type of elements in the list. But, your definition says

```
myLast [] = []
```

if you pass an empty list, it ll return you an empty list. In the signature you mentioned a single element but while defining you are saying a list. That is why Haskell is complaining about that line.

But when you remove that definition, and call `myLast` with an empty list, it couldn't match the input with any of the patterns defined for `myLast`. That is why it is failing with

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast
```

In this particular case, you have no valid input to work on. So, it is better throw an error, like this

```
myLast [] = error "Atleast one element should be there to find the last element"
```